# can not use semantic tab correctly

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I want to add semantic ui tab for menu and get content using Ajax, but I get the error following my JQuery code here. Can you help me understand what's going on?

```
$(' .ui.menu .item').tab();
$('#menuTarget .ui.menu .item').tab({ auto: true, path: '/dashboard/'+{tab} })
console.log({tab});
```

[image]

Comment: We can't do anything to help (except to tell you to research the issue) if you don't show your code.

Comment: $(' .ui.menu .item').tab();
 $('#menuTarget .ui.menu .item')
  .tab({
    auto: true,
 path: '/dashboard/'+{tab}
  })
  console.log({tab});
}

Comment: Add it to your question, good sir. And use the formatting tools, please.

Comment: @JMJanaka please check out what qualifies as a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then rewrite this question.  As it stands, I don't think you can be helped here.